# Count mailbox size used within ou

Tags: powershell

i am trying to show the mailbox space used for all users within one ou combined (mbx1 + mbx2 + mbx3 etc..).
not showing the users induvidualy but the used data combined.

i got so far:

```
#Connect Session
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -
ConnectionUri http://$env:COMPUTERNAME/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $Session

$domaininfo=Get-AcceptedDomain
foreach ($domain in $domaininfo.DomainName) {$stats = Get-Mailbox -
OrganizationalUnit $entry.Substring(0, $entry.IndexOf(".")) | Get-
MailboxStatistics}
```

how could i count all values from Get-MailboxStatistics value used size ?